# Linear algebra and substitution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix 
$$A =\begin{bmatrix} 3 && 1 \\ 2 && 1\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Compute $p(A)$, where $p(x) = x-2$.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: In $p(A)$ you should look at $2$ as $2I_2$ and you just replace $x$ by $A$.

Comment: Someone went through the trouble of properly formatting your question and you've overriden this edit with yours. I will roll back to the properly formatted version. Please make the edits on this version.

Comment: I got it, thanks. What about if p(x)= 2x^2 - x + 1

Comment: Same thing.${}$

Comment: Therefore it becomes:
2A^2 - A + I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about "$x$" as a matrix in the expression $x - 2$, then you should think about the "$2$" really as $2I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Since your "$x$" is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, then your $I$ should also be a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

So, $p(A) = A - 2 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} - 2\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.